# SQL result presentation asp.net vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

I have  table called tblA that looks like this

```
| FileName   | ProductName | 
|:-----------|:------------|
| 12345.jpg  |Honda        |
| 14578.jpg  |Toyota       |
| 11475.jpg  |Honda        |
| 11457.jpg  |Nissan       |
| 11145.jpg  |Honda        |
| 24879.jpg  |BMW          |
| 22222.jpg  |Honda        |
| 21545.jpg  |Honda        |
| 55552.jpg  |Honda        |
```

I am building an ASP.net VB.net website using gridView. 
If I do this query

```
select FileName from tblA where ProductName = 'Honda'
```

Then I want my asp.net gridview to show up like this:

```
|12345.jpg  |11475.jpg  |11145.jpg  |
|22222.jpg  |21545.jpg  |55552.jpg  |
```

Essentially like craigslist when you select the result to show side by side with pictures.

Can you please give me to the correct direction on how to do this with gridview?

If gridview is not the right approach then do I have to create a loop and build my own DIV HTML in VB.net?

thank you

Comment: I think repeatColumn is what I need. Still Not sure. I am looking into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use DataList control to achieve this and  have to use properties [RepeatColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns?view=netframework-4.8)=3, [RepeatDirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection?view=netframework-4.8)= RepeatDirection.Horizontal. You may also need to set [RepeatLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatlayout?view=netframework-4.8) property.